# EXCEL: matching two columns to another two columns and returning the result

Tags: excel

Bit stuck on a problem in Excel. I need to match two columns from Sheet 1 to two columns from Sheet 2, if the results match I need to then return column D's(Sheet2) value into Sheet1. I would of done this manually but this spreadsheet is huge and the reference table (sheet2) will be updated continuously.

My Spreadsheet:

- Sheet1: Column G and H
- Sheet2: Column B and C

I need to return the value in Column D (Sheet2) into Column A (Sheet1).

Any help on this would be excellent!

Regards,

Neil

Comment: I realised Concatenation would work just after I posted this as the two column combined would create a unique reference in order to match across.Good to see great minds think alike though! :)

Comment: it did for the type of data I was working with, the two columns I had to match merged created a unique reference which would only match the the help/reference sheet.